# can't make call to ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm unable to make a call to an ajax function, shown below (index.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.show_more').on('click',function (e){ 
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'gallery_controller.php',
        success:function(html){
            $('.content').append(html);
        }
    }); 
});
```

my button click is here (index.php):

```
<form action="" method="post">                
<button type="submit" class="show_more" name="next">Next</button>
</form>
```

this is my php script (gallery_controller.php):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "dbgallery");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT imagefile FROM tbl_images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '<h1>'.$row["imagefile"].'</h1><hr />';

}
?>
```

it seems to simply do nothing, i've tried a few things and nothing appears to work.. im wondering if ajax even works at all on my server.. i am a complete noob.

Comment: you wrapped it in a form, the ajax call is being sent, but the form is evaluated much before it finishes and refreshes the page. try adding `e.preventDefault();` right after the function opens and have the function `return false;` OR you can change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` so that pressing the button doesn't submit the form

Comment: In general it is important to use your browsers development console for such programming tasks. It allows you to see what the browser actually does. Without that you are flying blind, which never is a good idea :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following complete code. I think "e.preventDefault();" is missing in your code.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<form action="" method="post">                
<button type="submit" class="show_more" name="next">Next</button>
</form>
<div class="content">

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.show_more').on('click',function (e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'gallery_controller.php',
        success:function(html){
            $('.content').append(html);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>       

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a form for that button?
If you wrapped the button into a form for W3C validity issues it's ok, you can simply change your button type attribute from type="submit" to type="button".